# lenovo laptop not recognizing many usb device?

Tags: 14.04, usb, lenovo

My new Lenovo b40-70 laptop is acting weird sometime it recognizes some of the devices sometime it do not like:

Case 1: `lsusb` output:

```
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub  
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub  
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Case 2: `lsusb` output:

```
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp.    
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub   
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub   
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 138a:0011 Validity Sensors, Inc. VFS5011 Fingerprint Reader  
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0cf3:3004 Atheros Communications, Inc.   
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 5986:0652 Acer, Inc    
Bus 002 Device 016: ID 12d1:1f01 Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd.   
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Does this means there's some problem with my motherboard as my laptop is still in 30 day exchange so that I can exchange it or its just a bug as may be it is not being fully supported by Ubuntu 14.04.